# How do I DoS more than once using xerxes?

Tags: linux, denial-of-service, parrot-os

So I used the xerxes dos hack: https://github.com/zanyarjamal

I just wonder how I can use this more than once? Because I successfully dos'ed my test site but couldn't use it afterward.

Comment: To be clear, are you asking people to help you run repeated Denial of Service Attacks????

Comment: Hey! Well not really, I ran the xerxes DoS once and when I tried to re-run it, it just didn't work.

Comment: I'm not sure that this is an appropriate question for this site, but it you are hoping people can help you, you should probably include some details about what you have done and what the error is. "It didn't work the second time", doesn't really give any clues as to what the problem might be. Are there error messages? Any activty at all, a log? Please refer to
[How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
and
[How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Oh right, I'm new here so sorry if this shouldn't be here, well basically I ran the right commands as said in the GitHub and then when that DoS was done (successfully) I tried the same thing a second time but it didn't work. I'm just doing some tests.

Comment: Simply saying it did not work is probably not helpful. What did it do to make you say it did not work? For example did it simply exit it immeduately without doing anything? Was there an error message? Did your pc explode into a million pieces? Was there a blue screen of death/kernel panic?  Was there a stack trace/log file you can post? In short, what did it do?

Comment: Well, the DoS didn't work. I ran the commands and the voids popped up in the terminal just as it did when it worked but this time it didn't because the site worked fine.

Comment: Please place answers in Answer blocks. Later, you can accept your own Answer. Also see [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/173448)

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I just found out what I did wrong, I wrote the command `./xerxes.c www.fakesite.com 80`
instead of `./xerxes www.fakesite.com 80`, so my mistake was pretty dumb I was probably tired.

And yeah sorry for lack of information will keep in mind till the next time. 
Thanks!

Comment: I'm glad you worked it out. Hopefully you *now* understand the need to provide the details of what you have actually tried.
If in your original post you pasted a transcript of the terminal session, someone would probably *immediately* pickup that you do not run "C" files. Remember we can not see your PC. We rely on what you tell us. I do not know why you were down voted (people are encouraged to leave a comment as to why - it wasn't me BTW) but probably it was because you didn't provide the details of what was going on at your end.

Comment: Oh and thumbs up for being brave enough to admin your "pretty dumb" mistake! :-)

Comment: True! Once again I'm new around here and still in learning phases, I know what I did wrong and will improve it till next time.